# Таймер обратного отсчета до дня рождения

Tags: javascript

С таймером проблем не возникло, написан - работает. Проблема заключается в следующем.
Человек при регистрации указывает дату рождения, в аргумент функции инициализирующей таймер передается дата-дедлайн, в которую таймер сбрасывается и начинает новый круг отсчета.

Второй день ломаю голову над решением этой проблемы: как вычислить число миллисекунд, которое соответствует дню и месяцу рождения пользователя, но + 1 год от текущего.

Пример: пользователь родился 01.01.1970, необходимо передавать в аргумент функции числовое представление даты 01.01.2021, и естественно год должен быть вычислен не вручную, а динамически. Условно - currentYear + 1.

Спасибо

Comment: и что там, setYear, getYear методов в Date нет, или в чем проблема?

Comment: очевидно, если я задал вопрос, то не знаю в чем проблема, вроде как ресурс для этого и создан. А setYear, насколько я понимаю, могу конечно ошибаться, но применим исключительно к экземпляру объекта Date, в моем случае - это просто переменная с определенным числовым значением.

Comment: В дополнение к вашему комментарию, MDN вот что говорит про метод setYear:
"Устарело
Эта возможность была удалена из веб-стандартов. Хотя некоторые браузеры по-прежнему могут поддерживать её, она находится в процессе удаления. Не используйте её ни в старых, ни в новых проектах. Страницы или веб-приложения, использующие её, могут в любой момент сломаться."

Comment: и? заменили его на `setFullYear`. с каким у вас числовым значением переменная? Вы говорите про дату и миллисекунды. вот у вас есть `Date` и `Date,getTime`. Итого надо взять дату текущую, получить из нее год. Взять дату рождения и установить года как текущий+1. Потом вернуть секунды, если нужны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю такая примерная арифметика

```js
let birthDate = new Date("1970-01-24");
let month = birthDate.getMonth();
var day = birthDate.getDate();

let nextBirthDate = new Date(new Date().getFullYear() + 1, month, day);
let diff = nextBirthDate - new Date();

console.log(diff);

console.log(new Date(diff).getUTCFullYear() - 1970); // Gives difference as year
// 3

console.log(new Date(diff).getUTCMonth()); // Gives month count of difference
// 6

console.log(new Date(diff).getUTCDate() - 1); // Gives day count of difference
// 4
```

Comment: Вот я дурак :) 
Спасибо, то что нужно! Почему то совсем не придавал значения возможностям Date и пробовал делать все математически, в итоге результат один и тот же, как оказалось, но сложнее
   `const oneYearInMillisec: number = 31536000000

    const currentTime: string = new Date().toString()
    const userAge: number = Date.parse(currentTime) - dateOfBirthday
    const timeToBirthday: number = dateOfBirthday + userAge + oneYearInMillisec`

Comment: @NZWhale можете пометить ответ как полезный

Comment: С огромным удовольствием, но к сожалению не добираю 4х баллов репутации, пока что, для голосования...

Comment: @NZWhale Примите ответ там балы не нужны

Comment: Готово. Ещё раз благодарю)